# PHP gets JSON String as array

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

I have a form with 17 checkboxes. When one of these changes, JavaScript should submit the values to the server (running PHP).

I want to use JSON, because the checkboxes give two arrays which have to be seperated in PHP

In JS, I create an JSON-String, which I want to submit via POST and read and decode in PHP.
The String looks like this atm: `[["2015-06-26","2015-06-27"],["2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12","13","14"]]` - This is what I want it to be.

This is, what my AJAX-function looks like:

```
var fullArray = [dateArray, trackArray];
var jsonFullString = JSON.stringify(fullArray);
//jsonFullString == [["a","b","c"],["d","e","f","g"]]
$.ajax({
  type:'POST',
  url:'shownitems.php',
  data: jsonFullString,
  success: function(data){
    //More script. This comment is reached, because
    alert(data);
    // works.
  }
});
```

When I get it to PHP, and search for `$_POST[0]` the success function in JS doesn't show anything. When I search for `$_POST`, I get "Array.." back.

This is, what my PHP looks like (This is my test snippet):

```
<?php
echo $_POST;
echo ".";
echo $_POST[0];
echo ".";
echo $_POST[0][0];
$array = array();
?>
```

I am also using jQuery.

Comment: Use the `var_dump()` function to print variable content for debugging. There is no $_POST[0], and `echo $_POST` will print "Array" because it is an array - you'll only ever know what is inside with `var_dump($_POST);`

Comment: returns `array(0){}`... I'm not able to get the content of the arrays ... Even with json_decode(); ...

Comment: php cannot parse `[["2015-06-26","2015-06-27"],["2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12","13","14"]]`, the post request payload must be strictly key-value pairs.

Comment: `data: 'jsonFullString='+jsonFullString,` then look for (and `json_decode`) `$_POST['jsonFullString']`

Comment: Or just send the object: `data: {data: fullArray}` without any explicit encodings-decodings anywhere (not sure why people prefer to encode things twice for no real reason)

Comment: Already answered in this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20054392/how-to-post-json-array-to-php-using-jquerys-ajax-method) with the syntax `data: {mydata : myArray}`

Comment: PHP will only populate the $_POST array if you send the data using key=value pairs, and with the content-type `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` or `multipart/form-data`. The latter is very complicated to create in Javascript by hand, and the former is not able to send a json encoded string instead.

Comment: Thanks to all of you! I'm going to try your suggestions and answer, if it works ... or not ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should get your request content instead the `$_POST` variables.

Something like this would

```
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$obj = json_decode($json); //Will contain your array of two arrays
```

In case you wanted to get your post variables like you are doing, you could change your AJAX request and use:

```
$.ajax({
  type:'POST',
  url:'shownitems.php',
  data: {
    data: jsonFullString
  },
  success: function(data){
    //More script. This comment is reached, because
    alert(data);
    // works.
  }
});
```

And your PHP would be:

```
$json = $_POST["data"];
$obj = json_decode($json); //Will contain your array of two arrays
```

Answer (score 1):

In your JS:

```
/* dateArray and trackArray must be variables with values */
$.ajax({
  method: "POST",
  url: "shownitems.php",
  data: { date: dateArray, track: trackArray }
}).done(function(response) {
  alert(response);
});
```

In your PHP:

```
<?php 
  var_dump('Date: '.$_POST['date']);
  var_dump('Track: '.$_POST['track']);
?>
```